# Select alternate boot media from bootloader?

Tags: grub, boot-loader, syslinux

If I'm booting from USB, is it possible to edit SYSLINUX menus to select a distribution on an internal hd? I don't mean deferring to the internal boot partition, but selecting an internal partition distribution from a USB bootloader. GRUB?

It wouldn't be mounted yet, so I couldn't assume a path to the internal drive.

Does the booted os have to be on the boot partition?

Answer (score 0):

*If* this is possible in your situation and *if* you're doing this in SYSLINUX, then you can always change the `root=` value in your `syslinux.cfg` file.  Most often, you would link it to your first SATA hardrive, which I believe makes the value `root=/dev/sda0` or `root=/dev/sda1`.

Example:

```
DEFAULT linux
LABEL linux
 SAY Now booting the kernel from SYSLINUX...
 KERNEL vmlinuz.img
 APPEND ro root=/dev/sda1 initrd=initrd.img
```